# React Native giving the error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.enclosures[0].url')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, react-hooks, render

I have been having this problem, that I think is related to slow fetching.
I fetch from itunes API to get podcasts for this app I build.
on some podcasts it manages to work, but on others it shows that message,
Here is the error:

Error image:

[image]

Here is my code:

EpisodesView.tsx:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
//components
import Episode from './Episode';
import { useRootStore } from '../contexts/RootStoreContext';
import BottomGap from './BottomGap';
import PodcastTitle from './PodcastTitle';
import PodcastImage from './PodcastImage';
import SubscribeIcon from './SubscribeIcon';
import { fetchPodcast } from '../Api/Fetches';

//shows all of the episodes of a certain podcast
const EpisodesView = ({ route, navigation }) =>{ 
     //a constant to tell the <Episode /> what page he is on
     const fromMyListScreen = false;  
    // const { cachingStore } = useRootStore();
   
    const [podcast, setPodcast] = useState({
        title:'',
        image: undefined,
        description: '',
    })
    const [rss, setRss ] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        //fetch podcast
        fetchPodcast(route.params.rssUrl)
            .then((rss) => {
                setRss(rss);
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
    })
    
    //show all episodes of the podcast
    const showEpisodes = () => {
        return rss.items.map(item => {
            var track = {
                id: item.id,
                url: item.enclosures[0].url,
                title: item.title,
                artwork: item.itunes.image ,
                artist: rss.title,
                description: item.description,
                duration: item.itunes.duration,
                rssUrl: route.params.rssUrl,
            }
            return (
                <Episode track={track} key={track.id} fromMyListScreen={fromMyListScreen} />
            );
        })

    }
    var showTitle = rss?(
        <PodcastTitle title= {rss.title}/>
    ):(
        undefined
    )

    var showImage = rss? (
        <PodcastImage image={rss.itunes.image}/>
    ):(
        undefined
    )

    return (      
        <ScrollView>      
          {showTitle}
           {showImage}
           <SubscribeIcon />
            <Text style={{ paddingTop:20,paddingBottom:20}}>{podcast.description}</Text>           
            {rss? showEpisodes(): undefined}
           <BottomGap />
        </ScrollView >
    )
};

export default observer(EpisodesView);
```

the file where i fetch:
Fetches.ts:

```js
//fetches a specific podcast
export const fetchPodcast = (url) =>{   
    return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.text()
    })
    .then((data) => {
         return rssParser.parse(data)
     })
    .then((rss) => {
        return rss;
    })
     .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

I must say that it does exist,and not undefined, checking with console.log + postman
btw,
when doing this:

```js
var track = {
    id: item.id,
    //url: item.enclosures[0].url,
    title: item.title,
    artwork: item.itunes.image ,
    artist: rss.title,
    description: item.description,
    duration: item.itunes.duration,
    rssUrl: route.params.rssUrl,
}
```

it gives another problem, with another function thatrenders the duration,
so I believe it just doesn't manage to fetch it all before rendering
(btw it is the podcast 'syntax')

Do you have a solution?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are not wrong about the slow API response time, then you should consider adding a loading/fetching state variable (`const [isFetching, setFetchingStatus] = useState(true)` and just set the state value to false here:

```
fetchPodcast(route.params.rssUrl)
        .then((rss) => {
            setRss(rss);
            setFetchingState(false);
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
```

But it seems that the API does not return a defined value to `enclosures[0].url`, to make sure just log the API response and check if it does.

Comment: I tried to do the fetching, but it didn't work... of course I did : `console.log(item.enclosures[0].url)`, and it prints. however, it just stopps printing at some point and gives the error when reaching the 28th episode - and the url of that episode exists - I checked on Postman

Comment: maybe there's a possibilty to do a lazy loading? If so - do you know how to?